# Django suppress form errors

Tags: django, django-forms

If I have a bound form in Django 1.11, can I suppress the errors?

### forms.py

```
class FirstForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Foo
    fields = "__all__"
    exclude = ['many_fields_on_second_form']

class SecondForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Foo
    fields = "__all__"
    widgets = {
      'all_first_form_fields':forms.HiddenInput(),
    }
```

### views.py

```
def index(request):
  # they've submitted the first form at this point
  myform = FirstForm(request.POST)
  if myform.is_valid():
    secondform = SecondForm(request.POST)
    secondform.errors = None # <-- this doesn't work, "can't set attribute"
  else:
    messages.error('first form failed')
```

I do not want to suppress the errors in the template, only in the view. **Is this possible?**

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Note that Django 1.12 doesn't exist.

Comment: @Alasdair Sry, `1.11`. I have a model that is using two forms. When the first form is complete I just set those first form fields as hidden fields on the second form, which is the complete modelform. The design requires me to do the form in 2 steps.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you showed an example.

Comment: @Alasdair The reason why I need this should be clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a separate question I found this gem; set `initial` values instead:

```
initial = dict(map(lambda x:(x[0], x[1][0]), dict(request.POST).items()))
secondform = SecondForm(initial=initial)
```

In my view the hidden fields populate correctly and there are no errors.